# Slotmachine animation (preferably written in Java/SVG)

Tags: java, graphics, svg

I am looking for a program to show a slotmachine animation (preferablly written in Java/SVG). I'm interested in showing the rotating wheels with images of my own choice.

I have found
http://www.doit.org/java/slot/SlotMachine.java

which is the source code for an Applet.

- http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sh553/teaching/w3134-s07/review/SlotMachine.java
- [Basic Slot Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981647/basic-slot-machine)

do not have graphic support.
I am hoping there might be better/other solutions I could use for showing on a webpage.

http://www.treebuilder.de/default.asp?file=163540.xml

shows an SVG solution - this might be the closest to what I am looking for so far.

so far i could test the above applet by making a standalone java app from it. It works for the graphic part - the audio issue is discussed in

[how can i run an applet as an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174541/how-can-i-run-an-applet-as-an-application/13220880#13220880):

I will now at least be able to try out other graphics without needing the applet params to be defined in a web page. I'd rather have a standalone solution e.g. like a restful Java app.

See [`Wheel`](http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~jernej/slotmachine/SlotMachine.java), part of a larger [project](http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~jernej/slotmachine/) by [Jernej Vicic](http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~jernej/), and this later [variation](http://www.doit.org/java/slot/SlotMachine.java), incorporated into a [project](http://www.doit.org/java/slot/) by [Mark Boyns](http://www.doit.org/).

Comment: See also this [example](http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~jernej/slotmachine/igra.html).

Comment: Voting to re-open on the grounds of revised question and examples cited, although the one shown lacks adequate provenance.

Comment: unfortunately I can't vote myself - there had been 3 close votes already before the question was improved. Maybe it is a meta issue that close votes IMHO should be "resettable" by editing - at least the automatic close at 5 votes is IMHO somewhat counter productive.

Comment: More on _reopen_ [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415/163188). I've cited the original projects for SO [license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) compatibility. Sorry I overlooked your new [link](http://www.treebuilder.de/svg/slot/froot.svg) when editing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have examples of a slot machine *model*. For the *view*, you might look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552370/230513) that suggests using Unicode glyphs or implementing the `Icon` interface. Also, consider this MVC [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151403/230513) that illustrates rendering a `BufferedImage`.

Animating the visible face is straightforward, but a pseudo-perspective for adjacent facets would require a [trapezoidal transform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12749301/230513), available in JAI.

Addendum: *How can I run an applet as an application?*

Several examples of the *hybrid* approach are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513). Note that applets, too, must be constructed and manipulated on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Also consider [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for deployment.